# I want to place 3 divs next to each other with a background color

Tags: html, css

I want to place 3 different divs next to each other with a background color.

I tried floating everything to the left and it works but the background color disappears. If I don't float them, they are lined up under each other but the background color is there.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 1222px;
    margin: auto;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #6d757c;
}

footer .footercategory {
    float:left;
}

.footercategory li {
    color: black;
    font-family: NewsGothicBTWebCondRegular, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```
<footer class="footer">
    <section class="wrapper">
        <div class="footercategory">
            <div>
                <h1>Payment</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ROW 2 -->
        <div class="footercategory">
            <div>
                <h1>Unsere Zahlarten</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ROW 3 -->
        <div class="footercategory">
            <div>
                <h1>Unsere Zahlarten</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</footer>
```

If I float all left they are next to eachother but with no background

Comment: if you to use float, https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ you need to deal with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context ,but  display/table/flex/grid is easier to handle at first .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with the use of `flex`. Making your `.wrapper` class use flexbox will align the child elements next to each other. For the background colour, if you're wanting the background to remain consistent across all 3 columns, then set `background-color` on the `footer` element. Else, if you wish the background colours to differ, set each one separately on each `.footercategory` class.

```css
.footer {
  background-color:#6d757c;
}

.wrapper {
  display:flex;
}

.footercategory {
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
<section class="wrapper">
        <div class="footercategory">
            <div>
                <h1>Payment</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ROW 2 -->
        <div class="footercategory">
            <div>
                <h1>Unsere Zahlarten</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ROW 3 -->
        <div class="footercategory">
            <div>
                <h1>Unsere Zahlarten</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Lastschrift</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would flex three div's side-by-side, I have also added in some responsiveness just so you get an idea of how you can manipulate the boxes at different size screens.

```css
.section {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
 .section .section-inner {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1248px;
  margin: 0 auto; /* centers container */
  padding: 10px; /* this combined with the margin in the divs will make the margins appear consistent */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row; /* sort into rows */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;

  background-color: rgba(255,100,100,0.25);
 }
  .section .section-inner div {
   width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px); /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
   margin: 10px; /* space between boxes */
   padding: 20px; /* space inside boxes */
   box-sizing: border-box; /* calculates border and padding in width */
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: column; /* sort into columns */
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-grow: 1; /* forces singular div that falls beneath to be full width */

   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  }
   @media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .section .section-inner div {
     width: calc((100% / 2) - 20px); /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
    }
   }
   @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
    .section .section-inner div {
     width: 100%; /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
    }
   }

   .section .section-inner div h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
   }
```

```html
<section class="section">
 <div class="section-inner">
  <div>
   <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h1>Lorem ipsum </h1>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis nemo quas dolor optio autem! Veniam, dolore neque nam harum quae excepturi distinctio optio explicabo ipsum laudantium nesciunt et autem a.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify style as -

```
.footer {
    background-color: #6d757c;
    height: auto;
    float: left;

}
```

This will apply same color across the footer.

Answer (score -1):

Add background-color that you want to add to the `<section class="wrapper"></section>` tag and give a width of 100%.

then If you use bootstrap give class **md-col-4**  for each divs.

If you don't use bootstrap give the width manually like **width: 33%** and **display: inline-block** to each divs